# I accidentally created a Blank Activity in Android Studio, and deleted it afterwards. Now I can't install my

Tags: java, android

When trying to run the application, the following error appears
**Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
Installation failed due to: 'null'**

I think it now tries to access the Wear OS libraries and doesn't find them.

Comment: please share your logs

Answer (score 1):

Sure you haven't delete that one from your manifest file, too.
Check it!